# React componentDidMount confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused by some behavior and wondering if someone can help.  I have a React component which fetches movie data depending on the filter passed in through props.  Using console.log I can see that my componentDidMount() is only being called once, yet each time the component is re-rendered due to receiving different props a state variable that is only set in componentDidMount() changes.  My code is quite long so I don't want to post it all but I can if needed.  The snippet that is causing my confusion is below:

```
class MoviesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                        filterList : [], filter: {}
        };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("shouldOnlyCallOnce");
        if( this.props.filter.on) {
            if (this.props.filter.type == "title"){
                try {
                    const url = "mycustomapi.com/api/"+this.props.filter.title;
                    const response = await fetch(url);
                    const jsonData = await response.json();
                    jsonData.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
                    console.log("??");
                    this.setState({filterList: jsonData, filter: this.props.filter});
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            }
```

Despite the state.filter only being set there in the whole component, it changes each time my component is reloaded. Does anyone know how this could happen without console logging multiple times?

Comment: Along with this issue, my componentDidUpdate(prevProps){} prevProps is always the same as my current props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the only explanation is that you are modifying the contents of the filter outside this component.

Consider this:

```
let filterA = { title: 'foo' }

let filterB = filterA
console.log(filterB.title) // Shows 'foo'

filterA.title = 'bar'
console.log(filterB.title) // Shows 'bar'
```

Even though we never directly modified filterB here, the value changed. This is because filterA and filterB are referencing the same object, so of course they both change.

If you in your case pass the filter as a prop, and later modify the filter inside the parent, the filter will have changed in the child as well.

As a side note: What you are doing is called deriving state from props, which means that you are using the props to set the state. This is almost never good practice. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: Thanks that must be how this is happening, and I know I was just setting the state to the props while trying to debug.  The real issue I am running into is that my this.props is always the same as my prevProps in componentDidUpdate but I'll try and figure that out so thank you.

Comment: Wow your answer from here saved me, I just needed to create a new props object in the parent component instead of just modifying it to fix my other problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount will trigger when a component will do intiate render. After a props or state change, ComponentDidUpdate will trigger .Please check the link :  [react life cycle example](https://medium.com/@saharshgoyal/react-16-new-life-cycle-methods-inside-out-fdd269c43ccd)